# How to add a submit button in solrj API

Tags: html, solrj

I have build a local search engine with little data. I am using solrj for user interface i.e where user will write a query. Now the problem is that there is no submit button in that interface only user needs to enter and get result. How to add a button in solrj so that user have more than one option for request.

Any idea?

Comment: solrj isn't a front-end framework, it's just an API for java to talk to solr. you'll need to be running a web server (e.g. Tomcat) along side your solr indexer - you issue a command from the web browser to a servlet controller within the web server, the servlet controller invokes the solrj API (i.e whatever services/methods you've written to pull data from solr), store it in a session variable and pass it back to the browser for display

Answer (score 1):

The button can be created only in the front-end using HTML coding or anything of that kind but solrj is a API for java and it cannot be applied in the front-end. Run a web server along by the side and access the solrj API.